# At what point should I replace wooden floor boards on second storey

Tags: wood, flooring, structural, replacement

The floor on the second storey of my house is wooden floor boards laid in one direction between supporting beams at end end. Each board is 300 x 2600 x 55 and is wooden. What is the likelihood that these pose a safety hazard and how would I tell? They are likely as old as the house (50 years).

EDIT: SO asked me to edit this so responses are not based on opinion. So I clarified above that I'm asking about structural integrity, not aesthetics. Most answers/comments realized this so that's good.

[image: floor]

Comment: Replace? No, sand and re-varnish. Did that on pine boards that were 90 years old - came up a treat.

Comment: How thick and long were your pine boards?

Comment: 3/4" thick and between 2FT and 16 FT long.

Comment: Why are you considering replacing them? Are they rotten? Cracked/broken? Worn right through [seriously doubtful after a mere 50 years]? There are original floorboards in buildings here over 500 years old.

Comment: Modern store brought flooring usually does need replacement often, but you might want to refinish your flooring, does not look bad in the picture.  It will out last you, your children and probably your grand children.  Changing just for a designing fad usually only costs money and the fad ends before you are finish paying for it.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What's the context or motivation for asking?

Comment: Thanks so much for the input everyone. Some boards are a bit creaky so I am concerned about safety. Sounds like there's nothing to worry about. I'm in extremely humid NZ and 2 storey homes from the 1980s are very rare.

Comment: Re: creaky: if you have the ability to take the floor apart, you could consider applying some graphite powder between the planks. This should eliminate most if not all of the creaking.

Answer (score 5):

If a *single* board has rotted through, cracked, is broken or otherwise severely damaged beyond repair (and make sure you get *lots* of input on what "beyond repair" actually is), then you would replace that *one* single board.

You don't rip up an entire floor just because the wood is "old". If you don't like the look of a hardwood floor, then cover it with a carpet or LVP flooring or something similar (preferably something that isn't glued to the wood), but leave the beauty there for the next owner. Mentioning hardwood flooring in the house listing can actually *increase* the resale value of the house!

Your use of mm measurements indicates you're not in the US, so construction methods can vary (I believe that in the UK, buildings are primarily masonry - cement & brick), but here in the US, where we're very young (in comparison to the rest of the world), we have 400 year old houses made *entirely* of wood - floors, floor joists, roof rafters, studs, fireplace mantles, *siding* etc. - and nobody, but *nobody* is ripping out all this 400 year old wood to replace it just because it's "old". Restoration and rehabilitation projects will go to *great* lengths to *preserve* the wood, only replacing the smallest necessary section when *absolutely* necessary. Even wooden clapboards which have been exposed to centuries of weather *can*, in some cases, be restored.

If you're concerned about that dent on the right edge of the picture at about the 100mm/4" mark, that can, most likely be repaired if you want, or it can be left and considered "character". If you're interested in learning how to repair it, ask that as a new question here, or consider asking at [Woodworking](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/) where there is a *lot* of experience in working with and repairing wood.

Comment: Agreed!  A wood floor is a huge asset to a house.  You can refinish it.  If you don't like the look, cover it non-destructively.  Just don't glue/cement anything *directly* to it and don't fill it with nails because they will slowly leave rust spots that are hard for a future owner to remove.

Comment: I've dealt out a bunch of upvotes on comments and answers as well, but I figured I'd drop a supporting line as well: an old wooden floor is an asset to a house (both while you live in it and when you want to eventually sell it). You should be able to refurbish it and bring it back in good shape again.